# XML Parser - Data Binding C++ Builder

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, c++builder

I'm a bit stuck and new to C++. Basically I have an XML Document like this:

```
<Program>
 <DOSCommands>
   <Command>ipconfig /all</Command>
 </DOSCommands>
 <DOSCommands>
  <Command>chkdsk</Command>
 </DOSCommands>

 <Copy>
  <File>lol.txt</File>
 </Copy>
 <Copy>
  <File>BestMan.txt</File>
 </Copy>
</program>
```

Obviously my real XML contains lots of Copy and Dos tags. I have generated the code for this from the XML data binding. 
I can not seem to load these into my data structure properly. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How does it fail to load? Do you get any errors (add them to the question in that case)? And most importantly, how do you load the file?

Comment: Provide more details about your project, like some code snippets...

Comment: "*I have generated the code for this from the XML data binding.*" From *what* XML data binding?

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a homework assignment, why not use a library like [tinyxml2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/index.html) and don't reinvent the wheel? It has a very nice c++ interface.